# How to add a record to Many2many field in Odoo using XML file?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to create a record in a many2many field in `account.account` model.
I created a `Many2many` field in `account.account` model, which is related to `mapped.fields` model. Now I need to create a record for a COA using `xml` data.
Here is what I tried.

*.xml

```
      <record id="coa_field_a_10rf_annual_rev" model="coa.field.mapping">
        <field name="name" ref='mof.field_cit_a_10rf_annual_rev'/>
        <field name="cit_method">03</field>
      </record> <!-- Here a record has been created in the model but not related to its parent field. -->

      <record model="account.account" id="l10n_qa.1_bank_template">
        <!-- Method1 -->
     <field name="existing_coa_fields_ids" eval="[
       (6,0,[ref('mof.coa_field_a_10rf_annual_rev')])
       ]"/>

       <!-- Method 2 -->
     <field name="existing_coa_fields_ids" eval="[
       (0, 0, [ {'name':ref('mof.field_cit_a_10rf_annual_rev'),'cit_method':'01'}] ),
       (0, 0, [ {'name':ref('mof.field_cit_c_96sm_net_taxable_inc'),'cit_method':'03'}] ),
       ]"/>
    </record>
```

How can I resolve this?
Note: the external_id `l10n_qa.1_bank_template` which is created by Odoo itself.

Answer (score 1):

The `l10n_qa.1_bank_template` account is marked with `noupdate`, you can check it under `Technical / Sequences & Identifiers / External Identifiers`.

You cannot update such a record with the above code, To set the value of `existing_coa_fields_ids`, you can use a [function](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/developer/reference/backend/data.html#function)

In the following example, we use the record ID to call the `write` function on the `account.account` model using the values provided by `value` tag (passed as second parameter):

```
<function model="account.account" name="write">
     <value model="ir.model.data" eval="obj().env.ref('l10n_qa.1_bank_template').id"/>
     <value eval="{'existing_coa_fields_ids': [Command.set([ref('mof.coa_field_a_10rf_annual_rev')])]}"/>
</function>
```

You can also set the `noupdate` flag to `0` to update data then set it again to `1`

***Example:***

```
<function model='ir.model.data' name="toggle_noupdate">
    <value eval="'account.account'"/>
    <value model="ir.model.data" eval="obj().env.ref('l10n_qa.1_bank_template').id"/>
</function>
    
<record model="account.account" id="l10n_qa.1_bank_template">
    <field eval="[Command.set([ref('mof.coa_field_a_10rf_annual_rev')])]" name="existing_coa_fields_ids"/>
</record>
  
<function model='ir.model.data' name="toggle_noupdate">
    <value eval="'account.account'"/>
    <value model="ir.model.data" eval="obj().env.ref('l10n_qa.1_bank_template').id"/>
</function>
```

*Odoo encourages developers to use [Command](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command) to set the x2many field values*